# How to uninstall VMWARE-VMRC

Tags: uninstall, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I have this error when I try to uninstall using `vmware-installer -u vmware-vmrc`

```
/usr/bin/vmware-installer: line 421:  8988 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) LC_ALL="C" VMWARE_INSTALLER="$VMWARE_INSTALLER" VMISPYVERSION="$VMISPYVERSION" "$VMWARE_INSTALLER"/vmis-launcher "$VMWARE_INSTALLER"/vmware-installer.py "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get your .bundle file (in my case it is `VMware-Remote-Console-12.0.0-17287072.x86_64.bundle`) and make it executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/the/file
```

Then run this:

```
sudo ./VMware-Remote-Console-12.0.0-17287072.x86_64.bundle -u "vmware-vmrc"
```